# finding unknown entry of a matrix when nulity is given

Tags: linear-algebra

okay I don't know what is nulity of a matrix but I know nulity of a Linear Map, suppose I am given a $3\times 3$ matrix whose first entry is unknown say $k$ which I have to find if they say nulity of the matrix is $1$, please some one tell how to proceed?
Intuitively I think nulity of a matrix $A_{3\times 3}$ is $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3: Ax=(0,0,0)\}$ ?

Comment: If the nullity of the matrix is $1$, then you'll want to find a value for $k$ that makes the columns (equivalently the rows) of the matrix linearly dependent. However, if the other two columns (equivalently the rows) are ALREADY linearly dependent, you'll want to choose $k$ such that any two columns (rows) are linearly INDEPENDENT. Bottom line: you want exactly two linearly independent columns (or rows).

Comment: thank uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu :-* :-* $\heartsuit$ @IanColey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^3:Ax=\mathbf{0}\}$$ is called the [null space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28matrix%29).  It forms a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.  The dimension of this subspace is the nullity of $A$.

By the [Rank-Nullity Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), if $A$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix with nullity $1$, then it has rank $2$.  So, for the problem, you'll need to find a value of $k$ that ensures rank of $A$ is $2$.

Comment: $e^{\heartsuit}=1+\heartsuit+{\heartsuit^2\over 2!}+\dots$